# Disable selected autocomplete option in other fields

Tags: php, autocomplete

**Scenario:** I have a text field where user can search and select with autocomplete function where the list of items is retrieved from database. The user has an option to add more rows and select more items. So far this is working but I would like to achieve more control on the data input.

**Goal**

- Remove items from the suggested autocomplete list if it is already selected in previous row(s).
- If the user decides to type the item number manually, clear the textbox if (1) the input item already exists in previous fields or (2) the input item is not in the suggested list. (User sometimes decides to type in manually when the item number is short but alphabetically arranged at the bottom of the suggested list)

Text field

```
<input type="text" data-type="Item_ID" class="form-control autocomplete_tab" id="item" name="Item[]" placeholder="Item">
```

User can add new row with a button. Only code related to the textfield is shown:

```
function addnewrow() {
    var n = ($('.detail tr').length-0)+1;       
    var tr ='<tr>'+
                '<td class="no">' + n +'</td>'+
                '<td><p id="cyldiv" class="ui-widget">'+
                '<input type="text" data-type="Item_ID" class="form-control autocomplete_tab" id="item" name="item[]" placeholder="Item"></td>'+                
                '<td><a href="#" class="remove">Delete</td>'+
            '</tr>';
            $('.detail').append(tr);
}
```

Autocomplete code:

```
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_tab',function(){
type = $(this).data('type');
if(type =='Item_ID' )autoTypeNo=0;  
$(this).autocomplete({
    source: 'search.php',
    autoFocus: true,            
    minLength: 0        
}).focus(function () {
            if(this.value==""){
                $(this).autocomplete("search");
            }
        })

});
```

Code in search.php

```
<?php
require 'db/connect.php';   

$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

$query = $cn->query("SELECT Name FROM item_list_temp WHERE Name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'  ORDER BY Name ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['Name'];
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: your query `SELECT Nama` then your accessing `$row['Name']`? or it's just a typo?

Comment: @roullie Yep, corrected.